# PDO rather than MYSQL function

Tags: mysql, function, pdo

I was help last week to solve a problem with the script below.  It was resolved. Thanks again.  However many recommended using PDO instead.  How would this script need to be written for PDO? Is there an example tutorial that you recommend?

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

 mysql_select_db("bdcarterascv2", $con);

$COD_PAIS = '3';
$F_HASTACORTE = '2012-03-31 01:00:00';

$result = mysql_query("SELECT mcarteras.DES_CARTERA_CC                 AS 'Short Name of Fund'
     , mcarterasflias.DES_CARTERAFLIA           AS 'I/C'
     , msociedades.DES_SOCIEDAD_CORTO           AS 'Fund Manager Company'
     , mcarteras_clases.DES_CARTERACLASE        AS 'Class'
     , mcarteras_clasesesp.DES_CARTERACLASE_ESP AS 'Special Class'
     , dr_rentmovil_carteras.POR_RENTCARTERA    AS 'TTR year-to-date %'
     , dficha_mes.POR_REMUNERA_COBRADA          AS 'Mgmt Fee Effectively Charged'
     , dficha_mes.POR_GASTOS_TOTALESC           AS 'Total Expenses %'
     , dficha_mes.VR_CARTERA_FCORTE             AS 'Fund Size'

  FROM mcarteras
INNER
  JOIN mcarterasflias
    ON mcarterasflias.ID_CARTERAFLIA           = mcarteras.ID_CARTERAFLIA
INNER
  JOIN msociedades
    ON msociedades.ID_SOCIEDAD                 = mcarteras.ID_SOCIEDADADM
INNER
  JOIN mcarteras_clases
    ON mcarteras_clases.ID_CARTERACLASE        = mcarteras.ID_CARTERACLASE
INNER
  JOIN mcarteras_clasesesp
    ON mcarteras_clasesesp.ID_CARTERACLASE_ESP = mcarteras.ID_CARTERACLASE_ESP  
INNER
  JOIN dr_rentmovil_carteras
    ON dr_rentmovil_carteras.ID_CARTERA        = mcarteras.ID_CARTERA   
   AND dr_rentmovil_carteras.COD_PAIS                                       = $COD_PAIS
   AND dr_rentmovil_carteras.F_HASTACORTE                                   = '$F_HASTACORTE'
   AND dr_rentmovil_carteras.ID_FORMATO = 1
   AND dr_rentmovil_carteras. ID_COLUMNA = 5
INNER
  JOIN dficha_mes
    ON dficha_mes.ID_CARTERA                   = mcarteras.ID_CARTERA   
   AND dficha_mes.COD_PAIS                                                  = $COD_PAIS
   AND dficha_mes.F_CORTE                                                   = '$F_HASTACORTE'

 WHERE mcarteras.COD_PAIS                                                   = $COD_PAIS
   AND mcarteras.ID_CARTERATIPO = 4
   AND mcarteras.ID_CARTERAFLIA IN ( 3,4 )
   AND mcarteras.IND_PUBLICACION = 1
   AND mcarteras.COD_ESTADO= 1

")
or die(mysql_error());

// HTML ... Aliases from Mysql
echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Short Name of Fund</th>
<th>I/C</th>
<th>Fund Manager Company</th>
<th>Class</th>
<th>Special Class</th>
<th>TTR year-to-date %</th>
<th>Mgmt Fee Effectively Charged</th>
<th>Total Expenses %</th>
<th>Fund Size</th>

</tr>";

//<tr> specifies table row. for each <td> (table data) will specify a new column.  The     $row specifies the mysql column name (in this case using an alias)
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Short Name of Fund'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['I/C'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Fund Manager Company'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Class'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Special Class'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['TTR year-to-date %'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Mgmt Fee Effectively Charged'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Total Expenses %'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Fund Size'] . "</td>";

  echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't translate that to PDO. I prefer PDO for simple queries, but anything that complicated I do in pure SQL. I usually draw the line at a `JOIN`.